# Can we concatinate a string with a return type variable in HTML p tag?

Tags: python, jinja2

i am working on ML project where i need to mention the units in the results that my model predicts.
this is what i did :

```
<div class="result" align="center">
    {% if result %}
        {% for variable, value in original_input.items() %}
            <b>{{ variable }}</b> : {{ value }}
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
        <br> Predicted CO2 Emission is :
        <p style="font-size:60px">{{ result + g/MJ}}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

this shows

result + g/MJ

but what i want is:

result g/MJ

can anyone help me with this .

Answer (score 1):

```
<p style="font-size:60px">{{ result}} g/MJ </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply move the `g/MJ` out of the braces, as it's just literal text to be output:

```
<p style="font-size:60px">{{ result }} g/MJ</p>
```